# sem_timedwait aborts when passing NULL in the "abstime"

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, semaphore

According to `sem_timedwait` [implementation](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release/sem_timedwait.c), passing `NULL` instead of `abstime pointer` to
`sem_timedwait (sem_t * sem, const struct timespec *abstime)` should block (forever) until a signal interruption:

> If `abstime` is a `NULL` pointer then this function will
>      block until it can successfully decrease the value or
>      until interrupted by a signal.

However, when I am passing `NULL` I get the following error immediately without waiting:

> Program received signal `SIGSEGV`, Segmentation fault.

Why is that?

Comment: Why is this tagged linux, when the spec you refer to is for windows 32 bit systems?

Comment: If you want to wait indefinitely, why not use `sem_wait` instead? Neither the [(Linux) `sem_timedwait` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_timedwait.3.html) nor the official [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_wait.html) mentions a `NULL` time. And are you looking at the correct version of the source file, is it the same version of `pthreads-win32` you are using?